# Razorpay blank exception while create order Nodejs

Tags: node.js, razorpay

Get All Order API of razorpay on windows machine its work perfect but this API deploy on linux server its throw an exception and exception was blank object like {}.

My code is in nodejs API
my code is give below

```
var result;
await rzp.orders.all({
    count:10
}).then((data) => {
    result = [data];
    console.log(result);
}).catch((error) => {
    result = error;
});
return result;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an asynchronous function you should use a `try/catch` block.

```
try {
    const result = await rzp.orders.all({
        count:10
    })
    console.log(result);

    return result
} catch (err) {
    return err
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, But I already add try..catch and of course its give an Exception but exception was blank object. So what can I do?